# How do I make this example of an HTTP request work?

Tags: http, rust

I am trying to make the example in the documentation work, but I can't.

```
use http::{Request, Response};

let mut request = Request::builder();
request.uri("https://www.rust-lang.org/")
       .header("User-Agent", "my-awesome-agent/1.0");

if needs_awesome_header() {
    request.header("Awesome", "yes");
}

let response = send(request.body(()).unwrap());

fn send(req: Request<()>) -> Response<()> {
    // ...
}
```

The question is, how can I print the response in a string to save it? It seems it is not in the response.

Comment: You have an example of reading a `Response` in the [corresponding page](https://docs.rs/http/0.2.1/http/response/struct.Response.html). Does this answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly, which part I have to use?

Comment: There is that _inspecting the result of a request_ and then _Deserialize a response of bytes via json_. I never used this but I guess that getting a `String` won't be more difficult than getting a JSON.

Comment: I have no idea how to connect blocks of code you mention :(

Comment: I don't know what you mean with `connect blocks of code`. Maybe you are using the wrong crate? Note that `http` is not an HTTP client, it does not have any real code, only the HTTP types. A full-featured HTTP client is for example [`hyper`](https://crates.io/crates/hyper).

Comment: rodrigo is correct, the `http` create does not let you send a request! Try [reqwest](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.4/reqwest/) for an easy to use HTTP client.